# Como fazer disparo continuo em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

Boa tarde. Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde preciso fazer que  duas cameras fiquem tirando sequencias de fotos e parar somente depois de um comando pre definido.

No meu codigo atual precisa decidir o numero de fotos que deseja ser tirada, mas queria que ele continuasse tirando fotos infinitamente ate mandar parar.

obrigado e agradeço desde já

meu cogido atua:

```
import cv2
import sys

camera1 = 0
camera2 = 1
foto1 = cv2.VideoCapture(camera1)
foto2 = cv2.VideoCapture(camera2)
n = int(input("Quantas fotos deseja tirar?"))
file1 = ("C:/Users/Desktop/software/DISPARO/2CAMERA/Image1_%03i.jpg" %camera)
file2 = ("C:/Users/Desktop/software/DISPARO/2CAMERA/Image2_%03i.jpg" %camera)



while n > camera1 and n>camera2:
    ret, frame1 = foto1.read()
    ret, frame2 = foto2.read()
    cv2.imshow("Camera 1", frame1)
    cv2.imshow("camera 2", frame2)
    cv2.imwrite(file1,frame1)
    cv2.imwrite(file2,frame2)
    camera1 += 1
    camera2 += 1

print("FINALIZADO!")
```

Comment: tem que mudar o nome dos arquivos?

Comment: Uma dúvida. Qual tecla pararia? Qual ação vai parar? Porque se fica loop infinito,a perfomance vai fica ruim.

Comment: iria parar com o comando  Ctrl+C

Comment: @EdvaldoTeomar Você quer isso?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364173/stopping-python-using-ctrlc/21460045

Comment: não, gostaria apenas de saber como tirando fotos em um loop infinito

Answer (score 0):

Com a biblioteca [Matplotlib (plt)](https://matplotlib.org/) é possível realizar isto com a utilização de [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html)

Em que a tecla de [evento](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html) para parar a reprodução de imagem é em `event.key` com `if event.key == 'ctrl+c':`.

É realizada a conversão de BGR, padrão do OpenCV, para o RGB, padrão do Matplotlib, com `cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

#### Código

```
import cv2
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604435/7690982
def grab_frame(cap):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    return cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

def atualizar(i):
    imagem1 = grab_frame(foto1)
    imagem2 = grab_frame(foto2)
    im1.set_data(imagem1)
    im2.set_data(imagem2)
    # cv2.imwrite(file1,imagem1)
    # cv2.imwrite(file2,imagem2)

def close(event):
    # Tecla para fechar
    if event.key == 'ctrl+c':
        plt.close(event.canvas.figure)


#Inicialização
camera1 = 0
camera2 = 1

# file1 = ("C:/Users/Desktop/software/DISPARO/2CAMERA/Image1_%03i.jpg" %camera)
# file2 = ("C:/Users/Desktop/software/DISPARO/2CAMERA/Image2_%03i.jpg" %camera)

foto1 = cv2.VideoCapture(camera1)
foto2 = cv2.VideoCapture(camera2)
imagem1 = grab_frame(foto1)
imagem2 = grab_frame(foto2)

#Cria os dois subplots
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)

#Cria duas imagens nos subplots
im1 = ax1.imshow(imagem1)
im2 = ax2.imshow(imagem2)

# Escreve o arquivo
# cv2.imwrite(file1,imagem1)
# cv2.imwrite(file2,imagem2)

#Animação e atualização
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), atualizar, interval=50)

#Fechar
cid = plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", close)
#Mostrar o gráfico
plt.show()

print("FINALIZADO!")
```

> Obs.: Por que utilizar  Matplotlib e não o OpenCV? Por ser uma biblioteca de gráficos e ser muito mais completo do que o OpenCV. Por exemplo: Variados espaços de cores, subplots diferentes e geração de múltiplos gráficos para análise da imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma forma bem simples para resolver este problema. Utilize a função do `cv2` chamada `waitKey(delay)`. O que ela faz é basicamente aguardar por um tempo em milisegundos para que o usuário aperte alguma tecla. O que ele retorna é um `ord` do input.

Exemplo:

```
import cv2

camera = 0
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)

while True:
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    cv2.imshow("Camera", frame)

    #Sai do while caso a tecla apertada for "q" ou "Q"
    if cv2.waitKey(1) in (ord('q'),ord("Q")): 
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("FINALIZADO!")
```

Comment: o waitKey so funciona com a janela das cameras aparecendo, é possivel finalizar pelo CMD?
Assim, não precisa estar necessariamente as janelas das cameras abertas pra conseguir finalizar o programa.

Comment: Infelizmente não ;-;