# Como salvar e finalizar o codigo python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv, python-requests

Estou utilizando uma camera pra fazer captura de video, e salvar o video.
Estou tentando salvar e finalizar o codigo com um comando na propria IDLE(python) mas não estou conseguindo.

Atualemente para finalizar e salvar o programa é necessário estar com a janela aberta e pressionar a letra "q" ou "Q"...

Este é o meu codigo atual:

```
import cv2

camera = 0
camera1 = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)

while True:
    ret, frame = camera1.read()

#Sai do while caso a tecla apertada for "q" ou "Q"
    if cv2.waitKey(1) in (ord('q'),ord("Q")): 
        break

camera1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("FINALIZADO!")
```

Comment: Mas pressionando a letra Q não faz o que precisa? Não ficou claro o que você deseja fazer.

Comment: Eu queria depois, ocultar a janela, de visualização da camera... e mesmo assim o codigo funcionar, e pressionar uma tecla e salvar o video.

Comment: [Neste código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401247/como-fazer-disparo-continuo-em-python/401282#401282), utilize o [VideoWriter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html?highlight=videowriter), e depois coloque o [release](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html?highlight=videowriter#releasevideowriter) na `def close(event):` e dentro do `if event.key == 'ctrl+c':`